# activeadmin admin account cant access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I tried `rake db:reset` and now I can;t access it the admin@example.com|password it returns a invalid user/password when im logging in. I checked my database it's in there why is that so?

```
id          email              encrypted_password                                            reset_password_token  reset_password_sent_at  remember_created_at         sign_in_count  current_sign_in_at          last_sign_in_at             current_sign_in_ip  last_sign_in_ip  created_at                  updated_at                
----------  -----------------  ------------------------------------------------------------  --------------------  ----------------------  --------------------------  -------------  --------------------------  --------------------------  ------------------  ---------------  --------------------------  --------------------------
1           admin@example.com  $2a$10$cCUYBOKQHAZhpYgdLIZIWuQArkrsjpgIMu9/kk17127Oj.DKYwVxa                                                2012-04-19 15:23:02.857402  36             2012-04-25 02:37:36.689711  2012-04-25 02:31:55.088037  127.0.0.1           127.0.0.1        2012-03-09 16:23:58.779104  2012-04-25 02:37:36.692613
sqlite>
```

Comment: Why not just reset the password?

Answer (score 14):

do

```
$ rails console
>> AdminUser.create :email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I solved it by doing the following:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

And I was able to log back in!

That assumes that you won't mind doing a complete reset of everything!

Comment: Will rake db:reset do all of the above?

Comment: This might help: http://jacopretorius.net/2014/02/all-rails-db-rake-tasks-and-what-they-do.html